# OntoText Refine - UI Issues

Tags: graphdb, openrefine, ontorefine

I'm new to OntoText GraphDB v10 and was trying the new standalone OntoText Refine v1 to import data but the UI in the RDF Mapping extension seems to be broken, at least on Windows10 version (OSX version works fine).
Any idea how I can fix this? Hope I don't have to wait for a patch release.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilvyo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the new OntoText Refine v1.1

Thanks OntoText, I guess I wasn't patient enough...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with the placement of the file with the labels. Apparently, it was only for Windows OS that is why it was missed in the initial release of the application.